# Flutter http package get failed (69)

Tags: dart, flutter

When trying to import **http** package I can see the red underlining as it is error.

In terminal I tried running "flutter clean" and then adding "http: ^0.12.0" to **pubspeck.yaml** and running "flutter packages get" but it shows: 
*"Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (69)"*

Packages like "flutter/material.dart" are correctly imported. Don't know what to do.

Could this be issue with **http** not being back-compatible with flutter 1.0?

Comment: Sounds like you are behind a proxy which is not properly configured. See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/21316, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Using-Flutter-in-China

Comment: I think I am behind proxy, but flutter doesn't include option to overcome this, right? In python, for example, you can "pip install --proxy ... ".

Comment: Flutter uses environment variables as explained in the link above. If you are not in china you can use the normal URL for `PUB_HOSTED_URL` (https://pub.dartlang.org).

Comment: I set enviroment variable named "https_proxy" with correct values as stated here (https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/troubleshoot), but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I just checked the china link, sorry. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: OK, I resolved the problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

So the problem was I was behind proxy and added enviromental variables (https_proxy) as strings in quotation marks, where they should be added without " ". More here (https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/troubleshoot).

Answer (score 4):

On Linux/macOS:

```
$ export https_proxy=hostname:port
```

On Windows Command Prompt:

```
$ set https_proxy=hostname:port
```

On Windows PowerShell:

```
$ $Env:https_proxy="hostname:port"
```

If the proxy requires credentials, you can set them as follows.

On Linux/macOS:

```
$ export https_proxy=username:password@hostname:port
```

On Windows Command Prompt:

```
$ set https_proxy=username:password@hostname:port
```

On Windows PowerShell:

```
$ $Env:https_proxy="username:password@hostname:port"
```

[For more information refer this link](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall)

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you are behind proxy.
To see what proxy it is using use following commands on Mac -> Terminal

```
echo $ALL_PROXY or echo $https_proxy
```

Set appropriate proxy using -

```
export https_proxy="https://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>"
```

There will be a strange problem here though, if your password contains "@" then you can either try to replace it with special character `%40` or worst case change your password to something with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to V_P_N(Cisco) and check again.