# pub get failed (69); Socket error trying to find cupertino_icons in https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: android, http, flutter, dart, cmd

I recently downloaded the flutter SDK and everything was smooth until I cloned a project, when it was trying to get packages. which it just fails again, and again and again. 
I can access the website through my browser so it's not a proxy issue or something.

Any Ideas?
Here is the error:

````
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
Running "flutter pub get" in ethio_scholars_flutter_app.Got socket error trying to find package string_scanner at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
Got socket error trying to find package string_scanner at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...
Got socket error trying to find package string_scanner at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (69) -- attempting retry 4 in 8 seconds... ```
````

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/53665891/10409567

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are behind a proxy which is [not properly configured](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/21316). See also [the workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65812740/8342742):

> - Corporate firewall. Look [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall) for solution.
> - Env variables (Win system env vars). Create two of them:
>
>   - **name**: PUB_HOSTED_URL; **value**: https://pub.flutter-io.cn
>   - **name**: FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL; **value**: https://storage.flutter-io.cn